# Can't Ping other local ips on l2tp vpn connection, getting: ping: sendmsg: No such device

Tags: networking, vpn, ping, l2tp

I have setup an l2tp client using xl2tp to connect to an l2tp vpn server. The server connection requires that the connection be setup WITHOUT ipsec. So I have set up a basic xl2tp connection. The connections seems to work and I get an ip address from the vpn server, that is visible when I run ifconfig. However I cannot ping any ip's on the network I have connected to, there is a specific ip on that network I need to connect to: 10.10.251.32, however when I attempt to I get this error: "ping: sendmsg: No such device". I try the ping with command: ping -I ppp0 10.10.251.32. I have tried connecting to the vpn from other machines, the ip address that I get assigned are for example: 10.10.2.163, or 10.10.2.120, or 10.10.2.114 all in the 10.10.2.xxx subnet,

1. This is my xl2tpd.conf:

   ```
   [global]
   access control = no
   auth file = /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
   debug avp = no
   debug network = no
   debug packet = no
   debug state = no
   debug tunnel = no
   [lac vpn-connection]
   lns = xx.xx.32.43
   redial = yes
   redial timeout = 5
   require chap = yes
   require authentication = yes
   ppp debug = no
   pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd
   require pap = no
   autodial = yes
   name = thename
   ```
2. here is my: options.l2tpd

   ```
   ipcp-accept-local
   ipcp-accept-remote
   refuse-eap
   require-mschap-v2
   noccp
   noauth
   idle 1800
   mtu 1410
   mru 1410
   defaultroute
   usepeerdns
   debug
   lock
   connect-delay 5000
   name xxxxxx
   password xxxxx
   ```
3. I know that the connection gets made because I get a ppp0 interface and an ip address:

   ```
   ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
             inet addr:10.10.2.115  P-t-P:xx.xx.32.43  Mask:255.255.255.255
             UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1410  Metric:1
             RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
             RX bytes:98 (98.0 B)  TX bytes:110 (110.0 B)
   ```
4. The ip address of the server that I need to hit is: 10.10.251.32, when I try to ping it using a ping command specific to that interface:

   ```
   ping -I ppp0 10.10.251.32
   ```

I end up getting this error: ping: sendmsg: No such device

5. Thinking maybe it was some kind of subnet issue I connected to the vpn using multiple client clients simultaneously and got ip's such as 10.10.2.120, 10.10.2.114 and to ping each of the clients from the other to the same issue: ping: sendmsg: No such device. With all the clients I get connected and ifconfig returns the right  ip address.

The person administering the other networks swears that those ip addresses are up and running. I'm not sure how to proceed.. forgive a total linux newbie..

Comment: You pretty much don't have routing between your VPN tunnel and the internal network. VPN you're connecting to might have a LAN ip which VPN sees as its gateway while clients in the LAN might have another gateway, I assume. If you could add more detail as what's the dialing VPN LAN and an ipconfig or a PC over LAN.

Comment: Sorry still a bit of a linux / networking newbie so I didn't understand your reply. Do you mean that when my client connects its receives a different gateway that the other clients on that LAN might have?  As for the details of the connection, all we got was a instructions to connect to the l2tp vpn, which were an ip address and the username and password of how to connect to the l2tp connection.

Comment: See, for an example: let's say your VPN is just a PC with LAN and a WAN. Also, the LAN side of the VPN can be on the same subnet as the clients are (which you are trying to connect). But if the clients gateway is a different IP on the same subnet, then they'll talk to that particular gateway where your VPN has not relationship to talk to from its LAN. This is where you need routing even though you're on the same network since VPN tunnel is considered a different subnet, as it indeed is.

Comment: ok thank you. I think i get it. so I need to check with the people administering the VPN that i'm connecting to, to make sure that they have set up routing between the VPN server and the rest of the local network that I'm trying to connect to? Am i getting you correctly?

Comment: Yes, you do. If my guess is right, its pretty much to with the routing. I had gone through the same issue setting-up my **OpenVPN** and figured out it was due this.

Comment: ok so the person that set up the vpn servers says that all should be fine. I double checked by trying the same setup on a win7 machine and it worked fine, i was able to ping the ip i've been trying to reach so seems the issue is on my end.. :-(.. so Im stumped...

Answer (score 1):

In summary it was routing issue, I needed to add a script in the   /etc/ppp/ip-up.d folder, this script, called routes.sh would be run when the vpn/ppp interface came up.

/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/route

```
#!/bin/bash
route add -net 10.10.251.32 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev ppp0
route add -net 10.10.247.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev ppp0
exit
```

Then I also needed to enable ipforwarding in sysctl.conf, the command: `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

That was it..  set the routes when in the interface comes up, and enable forwarding.